# Why China don't have their cricket team?

Tags: cricket

as we can see there are limited teams which are playing cricket, and these teams have big names in the world, but why china don't have their cricket team for international?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is based on a false premise: China does have a [cricket team](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_national_cricket_team) which is affiliated with the ICC and has competed in various tournaments.